# Removing HTML markup from href link

Tags: php, markup

I recently made a page where I can monitor website traffic. I came so far as to replace a certain keyword with some html markup and making links clickable. But here is the problem. whenever I click a link with html markup it messes up the link with the `<mark>` and `<b>` tag. How do I remove the tags from the `<a>`?

Here is what I have so far:

```
$output = shell_exec('tail -n50 /var/log/nginx/access.website.log');

$output = preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a target="_blank" href="$0">$0</a>', $output);

$keyword = "twitch.tv|facebook.com|4chan.org|adf.ly|j.gs|q.gs|twitter.com|goo.gl|google.com|vk.com";
$output = preg_replace("/($keyword)/i","<b><mark>$0</mark></b>",$output);

echo "<pre>Access log:<br>$output</pre>";
```

Comment: Have you tried not putting those elements into the `<a>` elements, in your `preg_replace()` function call?

Comment: Why not use `strip_tags()` http://php.net/strip_tags - You can pick the tags you want to omit.

Comment: @DavidThomas not sure what you mean and how it will fix my issue.

Comment: @Fred-ii- when I use `strip_tags()` it removes the markup I want to have on the page and also removes the ability to click a link.

Comment: An example on that page shows that you can keep the tags you want to keep/allow `// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');`

Comment: @Fred-ii- yea I know I can keep certain tags but whenever I apply your method it removes the markup I want to keep on the page. I just want to remove the tags from the href link. I have no clue on how I can do that. (thanks for trying to help me out and baring with me)